# How to save updated table or dataframe in already existing csv file through shiny app?

Tags: r, csv, shiny

I am new to Shiny. My code is working fine. 
I am able to upload text in my table but I am not getting a proper way to save that updated table in my existing *.csv file.

Please suggest. Thanks in advance!

```
error.no.7 <- read.csv(file.path("file.csv"), sep = "," , header = TRUE)

library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- shinyUI(
    fluidPage(theme=shinytheme("readable"),
        titlePanel(h3("PUMA", style = "color:black")),
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
                tags$head(
                    tags$style("body {background-color: pink; }")
                ),
                textInput("Possible.cause", label="Add a new Possible.cause ", value="Enter Possible.cause"),
                textInput("Check", label="Add a new Check", value="Enter Check"),
                textInput("Remedy", label="Add a new Remedy", value="Enter Remedy"),
                actionButton("addButton", "UPLOAD!")
            ),
            mainPanel(
               tableOutput("table")
           )
        )
    )
)

server = function(input, output) {   
    row.names(error.no.7) <- NULL

    values <- reactiveValues()
    values$df <- error.no.7

    observe({
        if(input$addButton > 0) {
            # create the new line to be added from your inputs
            newLine <- isolate(c(input$Possible.cause, input$Check, input$Remedy))
            isolate(values$df <- rbind(as.matrix(values$df), unlist(newLine)))
        }
    })

    output$table <- renderTable({values$df}, include.rownames=F)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got to add a write.csv function, which replaces your "old" csv file. Be aware that it replaces it, so save a copy before testing.

In your actual configuration it will read and write the file in the path where the shiny app is saved (works on Windows7).

```
error.no.7 <- read.csv(file.path("file.csv"), sep = "," , header = TRUE)
#error.no.7 <- read.csv(choose.files("file.csv"), sep = "," , header = TRUE)

library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- shinyUI( fluidPage(theme=shinytheme("readable"),
                         titlePanel(h3("PUMA", style = "color:black")),
                         sidebarLayout(
                           sidebarPanel(
                             tags$head(
                               tags$style("body {background-color: pink; }")),
                             textInput("Possible.cause", label="Add a new Possible.cause ", value="Enter Possible.cause"),
                             textInput("Check", label="Add a new Check", value="Enter Check"),
                             textInput("Remedy", label="Add a new Remedy", value="Enter Remedy"),
                             actionButton("addButton", "UPLOAD!")
                           ),
                           mainPanel(
                             tableOutput("table"))
                         )))

server = function(input, output) {    
  row.names(error.no.7) <- NULL

  values <- reactiveValues()
  values$df <- error.no.7
  observeEvent(input$addButton, {

    if(input$addButton > 0) {
      # create the new line to be added from your inputs
      newLine <- isolate(c(input$Possible.cause, input$Check, input$Remedy))
      isolate(values$df <- rbind(as.matrix(values$df), unlist(newLine)))
      write.csv(values$df,file.path("file.csv"), sep = "," ,row.names = FALSE,append=FALSE)
    }
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({values$df}, include.rownames=F)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @PhiSeu. It worked for me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Inserted save button to your app, so you can easily save your data after entering fields

```
error.no.7 <- read.csv(choose.files("file.csv"),header = TRUE)

library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- shinyUI( fluidPage(theme=shinytheme("readable"),
                    titlePanel(h3("PUMA", style = "color:black")),
                    sidebarLayout(
                    sidebarPanel(
                    tags$head(
                    tags$style("body {background-color: pink; }")),
                    textInput("Possible.cause", label="Add a new Possible.cause ", value="Enter Possible.cause"),
                    textInput("Check", label="Add a new Check", value="Enter Check"),
                    textInput("Remedy", label="Add a new Remedy", value="Enter Remedy"),
                    actionButton("addButton", "UPLOAD!"),
                    downloadButton('downloadData', 'Save')

                       ),
 mainPanel(
           tableOutput("table"))
           )))

server = function(input, output) {    
 row.names(error.no.7) <- NULL

values <- reactiveValues()
values$df <- error.no.7
observeEvent(input$addButton, {

if(input$addButton > 0) {
  # create the new line to be added from your inputs
  newLine <- isolate(c(input$Possible.cause, input$Check, input$Remedy))
  isolate(values$df <- rbind(as.matrix(values$df), unlist(newLine)))
  }
 })


 output$table <- renderTable({values$df}, include.rownames=F)

 output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { paste(values$df, '.csv',sep="") },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(values$df, file, row.names=F)
    }
  )
  }

 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks Arun. I tried your approach, its working but my problem remains the same. I am not getting updated table after uploading text to it.

Comment: @PurvaNeema i have taken a .csv file which contains only three columns as you have seen in image, after that i have entered the 3 fields in shiny app and then i have click the button upload it automatically append to my table, so please take a .csv file which have are having 3 columns

Comment: I am not getting updated table when I ran the app again. In your screenshot as you can see that you entered your text it gets uploaded there but when you cancel it and again run the app you will not get that text you uploaded in previous run.

Comment: @PurvaNeema added save button to your app so you can easily download data into .csv file